# Python ElementTree gives Error when removing element from root

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm getting the following error when attempting to remove an element from the xml document.
"ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"
Here is the code, the error occurs on the line with the remove.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("AddInClasses.xml")
rootElem = tree.getroot()
for class2 in rootElem.findall("Transforms/class"):
    name2 = class2.find("name")
    if name2.text == "Get Field":
        rootElem.remove(class2)
tree.write("AddInClassesTrimmed.xml")
```

Answer (score 12):

You are looping over elements that are not *direct* children of the root. You'll need to get a reference to the direct parent *instead*.

With ElementTree that is not that easy, there are no parent pointers on the elements. You'll need to loop over `Transforms` first, then over `class`:

```
for parent in rootElem.findall("Transforms[class]"):
    for class2 in parent.findall("class"):
        name2 = class2.find("name")
        if name2.text == "Get Field":
            parent.remove(class2)
```

I added an extra loop that finds all `Transforms` elements that have at least one `class` element contained in them.

If you were to use `lxml` instead, then you could just use `class2.getparent().remove(class2)`.

Comment: Ahh Thank you Sir @MartijnPieters as I have been searching all day for this!  I was trying to use ElementTree.  I just switched to lxml to use getparent() and it worked like a charm.  Dear lord I purged this xml that was over 300K lines long, and took out all of these unnecessary <msg></msg> tags and now have a clean 5000 lines of XML.  Much cleaner to read and easier to work with.  Upvoted, repped, TU, etc.

Answer (score 0):

following also should work...

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse("AddInClasses.xml")
    rootElem = tree.getroot()
    for class2 in rootElem.findall("Transforms/class"):
        name2 = class2.find("name")
        if name2.text == "Get Field":
           rootElem.find("Transforms").remove(class2) #<<< see the lone change here
    tree.write("AddInClassesTrimmed.xml")
```