# Remove a specific xml tag with ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml

I am searching for a way to remove a specific tag `<e>` that has value as `mmm` within `xml` file (i.e `<e>mmm</e>`. I am referring to this thread as staring guide: [How to remove elements from XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593204/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-python) without using `lxml` library instead of using `ElementTree` with `python v2.6.6`. I was trying to connect a dot with the thread and reading upon `ElementTree api` doc but I haven't been successful.

I appreciate your advice and thought on this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
   <first>
     <a>123</a>                              
     <c>987</c>
       <d>
         <e>mmm</e>
         <e>yyy</e>           
       </d>         
   </first>
   <second>
     <a>456</a>                      
     <c>345</c>
       <d>
         <e>mmm</e>
         <e>hhh</e>            
       </d>
   </second>
 </parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It took a while for me to realise all `<e>` tags are subnodes of `<d>`.

If we can assume the above is true for all your target nodes  (`<e>` nodes with value `mmm`), you can use this script. (I added some extra  nodes to check if it worked

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
   <first>
     <a>123</a>                              
     <c>987</c>
       <d>
         <e>mmm</e>
         <e>aaa</e>
         <e>mmm</e>
         <e>yyy</e>           
       </d>         
   </first>
   <second>
     <a>456</a>                      
     <c>345</c>
       <d>
         <e>mmm</e>
         <e>hhh</e>            
       </d>
   </second>
 </parent>"""

# this is how I create my root, if you choose to do it in a different way the end of this script might not be useful
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

target_node_first_parent = 'd'
target_node = 'e'
target_text = 'mmm'

# find all <d> nodes
for node in root.iter(target_node_first_parent):
    # find <e> subnodes of <d>
    for subnode in node.iter(target_node):
        if subnode.text == target_text:
            node.remove(subnode)

# output the result         
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

I tried to just remove nodes found by `root.iter(yourtag)` but apparently it's not possible from the root (apparently it was [not that easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981081/6934388))

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Queuebee is exactly correct but incase you want to read from a file, the code below provides a way to do that.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file_loc = " "
xml_tree_obj = ET.parse(file_loc)

xml_roots = xml_tree_obj.getroot()

target_node_first_parent = 'd'
target_node = 'e'
target_text = 'mmm'

# find all <d> nodes
for node in xml_roots.iter(target_node_first_parent):
    # find <e> subnodes of <d>
    for subnode in node.iter(target_node):
        if subnode.text == target_text:
            node.remove(subnode)

out_tree = ET.ElementTree(xml_roots)
out_tree.write('output.xml')
```